# Which CSS tag creates a box like this with title?

Tags: html, css, fieldset, legend

I want to create a box like this with title:

[image: CSS box with title]

Can any one please let me know if there is a default CSS tag to do this? Or do I need to create my custom style?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the `fieldset` HTML tag, which you can then style with CSS. E.g.,

```html
    
    <fieldset style="border: 1px black solid">

      <legend style="border: 1px black solid;margin-left: 1em; padding: 0.2em 0.8em ">title</legend>

      Text within the box <br />
      Etc
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: you should copy this exact html code in your answer (in addition of your html source code already there). This code will be interpreted and displayed in this post, and that would show it is works exactly as advertised. I am not yet able to edit your post to do just that...

Comment: VonC, I tried doing that, but it stripped out all my HTML. Leaving just my text.

Comment: It only allows basic literal HTML so its probably that the fieldset tag is not allowed or something like that

Comment: its worth noting that fieldsets are to be used for forms only.

Comment: @Buzz Why? What's the downside?

Comment: @Flimm The same reasons one should not use `<ul>` or `<ol>` just to create an indented paragraph:  (1) The element has specific meaning and that meaning is not about how it looks.  (2) It isn’t guaranteed to be rendered that way, just because a majority of browsers currently render it that way.  In other words, relying on a fieldset element to look a certain way may break in the future.

Comment: you need . "width: auto"

<legend style="margin-left: 1em; padding: 0.2em 0.8em ;width: auto">title</legend>

Answer (score 19):

If you are not using it in forms, and instead want to use it in an non-editable form, you can do this via the following code -

```css
.title_box {
  border: #3c5a86 1px dotted;
}

.title_box #title {
  position: relative;
  top: -0.5em;
  margin-left: 1em;
  display: inline;
  background-color: white;
}

.title_box #content {}
```

```html
<div class="title_box" id="bill_to">
  <div id="title">Bill To</div>
  <div id="content">
    Stuff goes here.<br> For example, a bill-to address
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

from http://www.pixy.cz/blogg/clanky/css-fieldsetandlabels.html

```css
fieldset {
  border: 1px solid green
}

legend {
  padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid green;
  color: green;
  font-size: 90%;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Subscription info</legend>
    <label for="name">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    <br />
    <label for="mail">E-mail:</label>
    <input type="text" name="mail" id="mail" />
    <br />
    <label for="address">Address:</label>
    <input type="text" name="address" id="address" size="40" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

This will give you what you want

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        legend {border:solid 1px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Test</legend>
        <br /><br />
    </fieldset>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know (correct me if I'm wrong!), there isn't.

I'd recommend you to use a div with a negative-margin-h1 inside. Depending on the semantic structure of your document, you could also use a fieldset (HTML) with one legend (HTML) inside which approximately looks like this by default.

Comment: Thanks, yes you are right! I was looking for fieldset/legend option. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this out.

```
<fieldset class="fldset-class">
    <legend class="legend-class">Your Personal Information</legend>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Name</label></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='name'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Address</label></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='Address'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>City</label></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='City'></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3tnqgLr5/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I think this example can also be useful to someone:

```css
.fldset-class {
    border: 1px solid #0099dd;
    margin: 3pt;
    border-top: 15px solid #0099dd
}

.legend-class {
    color: #0099dd;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="fldset-class">
    <legend class="legend-class">Your Personal Information</legend>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Name</label></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='name'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Address</label></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='Address'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>City</label></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='City'></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
```