# Create box with title/legend, in CSS

Tags: css, org-mode

As a follow-up to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113640), I'd like to add a title to a `<pre>` box, indicating what kind of code is inside it (e.g. `R`, `sh`, `perl`, ...).  But I can't use a `<div>` as in the previous question, because the `<pre>` is generated by another tool ([org-mode export](http://orgmode.org/)).  It looks like this:

```
<pre class="src src-R">
here <- is(the=code)
</pre>
```

So I'm hoping to create a `src-R` class that adds an `R` title to the `<pre>` box, in pure CSS, or if that's not possible, using some additional Javascript.

Any pointers appreciated!

Comment: it's a shame you can't switch from the `<pre>` tag, because the `<fieldset>` tag with a `<legend>` tag inside does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it using only CSS with `.src-R:before`.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/myAhS/

```
.src-R:before {
    content: 'R'
}
.src-Perl:before {
    content: 'Perl'
}
.src:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000
}
.src {
    position: relative;
    padding: 25px 9px 9px 9px;
    border: 1px solid #000
}
```

[`:before`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoelement-before) works [in IE8+ and all modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/css-gencontent).

If you need IE7 or lower support, JavaScript will be needed.

Comment: That's just awesome, I'd never seen `:before` or `:after` before.  You can tell I learned CSS on the streets. =)