# Creating a border around box that stops at title

Tags: html, css

I'd like to create a box around some text, with the border stopping at the point of the title. See below for example.

[image]

I've found [this in an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113640/which-css-tag-creates-a-box-like-this-with-title), but as it's now 10 years old I'm wondering whether it's out of date, or whether there is a better fix.

I've attempted a similar method myself, and am more or less there. I'm curious whether there is a go-to method for achieving this or whether my method is fine.

```css
.welcome-box {
  border: 1px solid #e75d14;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

.welcome-box h2 {
  margin-top: -18px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="welcome-box">

<h2>WELCOME</h2>

<p>Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text </p>

</div>
```

Comment: Looks good to me :)

Comment: That's the way to go, I would think. :-)

Comment: I think this question is out-of-scope for Stack Overflow - you may have more luck over at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `<fieldset>`/`<legend>` tags are exactly what you are looking for, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[`<fieldset>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset)** and **[`<legend>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/legend)** tags do that behavior by default, but the semantics police may be upset if it's used for something other than form controls. Regardless the `<fieldset>` **[content categories](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories)** are more than enough to cover any purpose a `<div>` is permitted to have.

### Demo

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

legend {
  text-align: center;
}

legend h2 {
  padding-bottom: 0
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="welcome-box">
  <legend>
    <h2>WELCOME</h2>
  </legend>

  <p>Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum
    text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text </p>

</fieldset>
```

Comment: in such case i would consider some complicate border/background with linear gradient but why complicating if there is a sematic element for it +1