# A "title" or a "header" for a div

Tags: html, css, asp.net, styling

I am building a simple web-page with a few sections in it and I've been stomped at how to solve one little styling issue.

I have several DIVs with solid border and a few other GUI items (text boxes, buttons, etc) inside each one. Each DIV kind of "boxes" related items into a nice, visually pleasing and meaningful way. However, I would like to add a title or a caption onto the DIV in the middle of the border to describe that box's function. So far I can add text below the border or above, but not in the middle. Is that even possible?

Thank you!

What I have:
[image: what I have]

What I want:
[image]

Comment: Would you share some code? that we can see what you already tried.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which CSS tag creates a box like this with title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113640/which-css-tag-creates-a-box-like-this-with-title)

Comment: @sajjad rezaei Yeah, the title is misleading, thats why I didn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want looks like a `fieldset` element with a `legend` tag inside, but  I wouldn't recommend using them.
Just use `position: absolute` like this:

```
<div class='section'>
    <header>Header</header>
    ....
</div>
```

```
.section{
    position: relative;
}

.section header{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    background: white;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. When I plug your data into my project, nothing shows up. I put a border into the .section and I get a box, but no Header. What am I doing wrong? Fieldset seems to be working, why is it not recommended?

Comment: Fieldset/legend had issues if you try to style them with CSS as far as i remember. If you are fine with default view, it is ok to use them. Cannot say what's wrong with your code untill i see it =)

Comment: what kind of issues? I can style them just fine with CSS.

Comment: There are some limitation and "several special styling considerations" as [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset) says. Also checkout this [example](https://codepen.io/JaredSpb/pen/vYpLRJP)

Answer (score 2):

What you looking for is build in HTML nativly: The border Frame is part of the `<fieldset>` while the title is the `<legend>`

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Header</legend>
</fieldset>
```

As (wrongly) stated by others, that solution would not work with Bootstrap. The solution to that is quite easy by reverting the Bootstrap overwrites with `all: revert;`

```css
.revert,
.revert legend {
  all: revert;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap 5 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">



<!-- Body -->
<fieldset>
  <legend>Header</legend>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="revert">
  <legend>Header</legend>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: This wont work when using bootstrap 5. I miss the<fieldset>/<legend> tagging.

Comment: @mono this is not a Bootstrap question and even Bootstrap has fieldset and legend as this is a HTMl solution and Bootstrap is a CSS Framework.

Comment: My comment wasn't a negative poke at your answer, just a note I left here for anyone stumbling across the answer in the future. <fieldset> is nice and handy, but in the long run you're better off making your own as @Jared answered below.